# C# Redis Client exceeded 6000 connections per hour limit

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

We are getting the following error. We found that we have to upgrade to a premium plan of servicestack. But their License plan is a bit confusing, it says number of developers, can we use this for multiple IIS servers and redis clients that spans across multiple environments ?

```
The free-quota limit on '6000 Redis requests per hour' has been reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a commercial license.

ServiceStack.Redis.RedisException: Unable to Connect: sPort: 52287
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.CreateConnectionError()
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendReceive[T](Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs, Func`1 fn, Action`1 completePipelineFn, Boolean sendWithoutRead)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.SendExpectSuccess(Byte[][] cmdWithBinaryArgs)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisNativeClient.Set(String key, Byte[] value, Int32 expirySeconds, Int64 expiryMs)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.<>c__DisplayClass4f`1.<Set>b__4b(RedisClient r)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Exec(Action`1 action)
   at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.Set[T](String key, T value, TimeSpan expiresIn)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes the developer licenses are **royalty-free** so anything licensed developers create with ServiceStack.Redis can be deployed to unlimited servers at no additional cost.